# Zend to Laminas Conversion Module (application) could not be initialized

Tags: php, laminas

I converted a Zend 2.3 project to laminas.  I followed the instruction and made alteration to my `composer.json` file.  I then ran composer update.
When trying to launch the application, I saw the following error.

```
Uncaught Laminas\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Application) could not be initialized. in /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:210
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(182): Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName()
#1 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(104): Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule()
#2 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(331): Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules()
#3 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(180): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners()
#4 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(127): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent()
#5 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Application.php(263): Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules()
#6 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/public/index.php(22): Laminas\Mvc\Application::init()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 210
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class named 'Module' in namespace 'Application'? Do you have in composer.json something like

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
      }
   }
```